# Secure Copy (scp) the latest file which arrives at a given folder?

Tags: python, bash, copy, scp

I need to write a script in `bash/python` to `scp` the latest file which arrives at a given folder.That is I am continously getting files into a folder say (`/home/ram/Khopo/`) I need to scp it into `xxx@192.168.21.xxx` in `/home/xxx/khopo/`.

I googled and got this result

```
file_to_copy=`ssh username@hostname 'ls -1r | head -1'`
echo copying $file_to_copy ...
scp username@hostname:$file_to_copy /local/path
```

But I want to know whether it is possible do this such that it runs only when a new folder arrives at the source(`/home/ram/Khopo/`) and waits for the file to reach the folder and do it immediately when it has arrived

Comment: Linux should have watchdog system which let you observer folder/file execute function when something changed - python module which uses it [watchdog](https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/). If sytem doesn't have watchdog then you can use endless loop in which you check folder and sleep if there was no changes.

Comment: If you want to monitor a remote directory then `rsync` is a great tool, but you will have to run continuously to monitor the directory. If you have the possibility to run the script in the remote machine, check `ionotifywait` here: https://superuser.com/questions/956311/continuously-detect-new-files-with-inotify-tools-within-multiple-directories-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have suggested you can use `inotifywait`, below an example of what you could do in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter ssh password"
IFS= read -rs password  # Read the password in a hidden way

inotifywait -m -e create "/folder_where_files_arrive" | while read line
do
    file_to_copy=$(echo $line | cut -d" " -f1,3 --output-delimiter="")
    echo copying $file_to_copy ...
    if [[ -d $file_to_copy ]]; then  # is a directory
       sshpass -p $password scp -r username@hostname:$file_to_copy /local/path
    elif [[ -f $file_to_copy ]]; then  # is a file 
       sshpass -p $password scp  username@hostname:$file_to_copy /local/path
    fi
done
```

Then you would ideally put this script to run in background, e.g.,:

```
nohup script.sh &
```

For `sshpass` you can install it in ubunut/debian with:

```
apt install sshpass
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! could you please tell me how to give the passowrd for scp as well in bash. I am new

Comment: @RAMSHANKERG there are several ways, I will give an example. Please select this answer as response If you are satisfied.

Comment: Also..I am copying several types of files...such as files in a folder or files alone, how can I incorporate all this.if I use scp -r it only copies folder whereas if i dont use it, it copies only files.

Comment: And I observe that it only copies those files which I am copying to the folder, what about files which goes into it programmatically?

Comment: you can check if the newly created event is for a file or folder. I added code

Comment: much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 3):

I would try to sync the remote directory. This should give you nice outlook, how to do that:

rsync:

https://askubuntu.com/a/105860

https://www.atlantic.net/hipaa-compliant-cloud-storage/how-to-use-rsync-copy-sync-files-servers/

or other tools for syncing:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_synchronization_software